# Tor Hidden Service Not Working

Tags: onion-services

I've started an NGINX site on the port 8034 which I can access in the Tor Browser as well as a normal browser.

I've set the Tor Service to use the port 8034 so as make it an onion site.
When I start Tor, I don't get any error logs but the generated hostname doesn't work and I can't access it on the tor network, despite the website on NGINX working.

These are the only enabled lines in my torrc

```
DataDirectory /var/lib/tor
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 8034 [My VPS IP]:8034
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your HiddenServicePort line. Here is an example:

```
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

The first 80 is the port that you expect traffic to come in on

The IP address needs to be pointing to your localhost which is 127.0.0.1

the second 80 is the port that your web server is using.

If you use:

```
HiddenServicePort 8034 127.0.0.1:8034
```

Then someone who connects to your onion service will be connecting to http://myonionabcxyz.onion:8034

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought the ports were supposed to be the same, but it works now. Solved